# Generic and Overloads with .NET Compact Framework

Tags: c#, serialization, compact-framework

**Please see the edit below, I've made the question much simpler!**

I would like to create my own serialization method.

I have a generic reference I'd like to serialize.  This generic reference has a chance of just being a typical value type (single, int16 etc).  In that case, I would like to just call the appropriate overloaded method: `BitConverter.GetBytes( genericRefThatIsACommonValueType )` without resorting to type checking (for `single` or `int16` and etc).

First off, I'd like to know if what I'm asking is possible (because it would look and feel a lot nicer).  And secondly, do you think there is a better way of tackling this type of problem?  Thanks.

========= EDIT ==========

Why does the method bar() not compile, when I've checked that data has a type that BitConverter.GetBytes(..) should support in it's overloads.  Can I get something similar to this working?

```
public class foo<T>
{
    T data;

    public foo(T arg)
    {
        data = arg;
    }

    public void bar()
    {
        if(data.GetType() == typeof(int) || data.GetType()== typeof(float))
        {
            BitConverter.GetBytes(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess before do any thing, it's good look at this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ProperBenchmarkingToDiagnoseAndSolveANETSerializationBottleneck.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the `bar()` method is that *you* know it's a type supported by `BitConverter.GetBytes()`, but `data` is still of type T with no constraints. It would work if there was a `BitConverter.GetBytes<T>()` method.

I'm afraid you'll have to cover each overload manually:

```
switch (Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)))
{
    case TypeCode.Int32:
        BitConverter.GetBytes((Int32)data);
        break;
    case TypeCode.Int64:
        BitConverter.GetBytes((Int64)data);
        break;
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to determine if it is a primitive type:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive(v=vs.110).aspx

Keep in mind that string is not a value type, so if you'd like to handle that, you'll want to check whether it is a string. but, at least at that point it's a lot less checking.

Comment: An alternative is using `Type.GetTypeCode(data.GetType);` instead and use its result in a `switch` statement, the idea is the same though.

Comment: That link you sent is very useful, but it doesn't answer my question in full.  But thank you.